# Assumed decimal point in string convert in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using SSIS and have a flat fixed width file I'm pulling into a SQL DB table that is coming over as a string.  It comes over with 0000531164 and that needs to write to the SQL DB as 5311.64.

I'm using a derived column to remove the 0's but am not sure if I need to add a . to the expression or if there is a way to convert an assumed decimal to currency properly?

```
Current expression = (DT_WSTR,50)(DT_I8)(SUBSTRING(<Table Name>,21,16))
```

Comment: try to divide by 100

Answer (score 0):

Another way, on the SQL Server side, would be to use `STUFF` and then just `CAST` it.

```
declare @var varchar(64) = '0000531164'

select cast(stuff(@var,len(@var) - 1,0,'.') as decimal(32,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

In derived Column:

```
(DT_CY)([FieldName])/100
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I explained it (or fully understood) what was needed at this point.  I have a fixed width file that has client level and account level in same file. So those are separated in the package using conditional split and then I needed to separate the digits with a . to get the proper value.  I ended up using this expression (DT_CY)(SUBSTRING(Filler,37,11) + "." + SUBSTRING(Filler,48,2)) where "Filler" is my fixed width values and the numerics are the start and length of the fixed width file.

Was overthinking it, this thread helped baseline what was needed.  Thank you all.